# Writing a Build Script for a Play! Framework application

Tags: java, build, playframework

How are people writing builds for their Play applications?
I understand that you can run `play auto-test` on the command-line, however, I would like to do a bit more than just execute the tests.

So for example, if I wanted to add checkstyle and clover to my build, I could easily write an Ant script that would check those two things and fail if there are any checkstyle errors or the clover coverage is not 90%.

I was just wondering whether there already was a "Play" way of doing what I have just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not, not as far as I know, although there are addons to use ant/maven in Play, you could try to integrate them. But users may skip then and use the normal play.

An idea would be to modify the Play python script to run these validations before any action, but that would require all developers to use that modified script.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "Play" way that I know of, either. I've used [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) in the past with some Play apps to do that kind of stuff.

Comment: Do you have any public code for your gradle script, that I could view ?